# Hyperboloid of one sheet has only one closed geodesic

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $S : x^2+y^2-z^2 = 1 $ be the hyperboloid of one sheet. We know that there exists a closed geodesic, namely the unit circle $\{(\cos\theta, \sin\theta,0) , \theta \in [0,2\pi]\}$, since it is the locus of fixed points of the reflection along the $xy$ plane . The claim of uniqueness should follow from Clairaut's relation, however I can't see why that is.
In fact, the problem can be solved in a more general case; A surface of revolution with negative gaussian curvature has at most one simple closed geodesic. Can anyone enlighten me on how this follows from Clairaut's relation?

Comment: Clairaut will tell you more — namely, that every other geodesic must be unbounded. But what you’re looking for is an immediate consequence of Gauss-Bonnet.

Comment: @TedShifrin Could you please expand a bit on why Clairaut tells us they are unbounded?

Comment: In the notation I use, $r\cos\phi$ is constant along geodesics. This tells you that as $r$ increases, $\phi$ must also increase. So $r$ cannot be bounded above (because if there's a maximum $r$ we would have $\phi=0$, and if the geodesic spirals to a parallel $r=r_0$, likewise $\phi\to 0$).

Comment: That’s minimum, not maximum!

Comment: A complete surface of negative curvature with cyclic fundamental group indeed has at most one simple closed geodesic.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ r_i, \psi_{i}, r_{min}$ be initial radius, initial angle of arc filament to meridian and minimum radius at waist.

The arc tracing is decided entirely compelled by Clairaut's Law .

There are three cases.

1. If $ \psi = \pi/2 ,~ ~r= r_{min} $ it is stuck at $r_{min}= r_i$ at the start keeping  always to the circumference and it is the lone closed geodesic. The other two following cases are open geodesics:
2. The case $ \psi> \sin^{-1}\dfrac{r_{min}}{r_{i}}$ the filament arc comes to a point $ r> r_{min} $ where it makes $\psi = \pi/2$ and retraces its path as open geodesic to only one side, else the angle $ \psi $ would goes imaginary.
3. The case $ \psi< \sin^{-1}\dfrac{r_{min}}{r_{i}}$ the arc filament goes past the waist to infinite distances parallel to symmetry axis as an open geodesic, all radii and $\psi $ are real.

[image]

[Geodesics on a 1-sheet hyperboloid of revolution](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/HyperboloidGeodesics/)